# Setting the corner radius of a tableview presented inside a popovercontrol in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am setting the contentviewcontroller of popover control to be a UiTableView.

The view that is presented is rounded at corners. I tried setting the corner radius of the TableView to zero. But this is not changing anything.

Comment: The round corners are a property of the popover, not the content view. I'm not sure, whether one can customise the popover.

Comment: I am using the custom Popover.Like all the delegate methods are overriden. But I couldnot find anything where I could customize the corner radius.

Comment: Have a look at the other question I referenced. I think it solves your problem.

Comment: Show some code you have tried or the question could get closed.